# Adding multiple columns together based on condition

Tags: r

I want to add together a few columns of data, similar to this,

```
mtcars[,12] <- mtcars[2]+mtcars[4]+mtcars[6]
```

but I want to do it based on specific conditions. An example of a condition would be if the mean of one of the columns is greater than a certain number, similar to this

```
mtcars[,12] <- 
  ifelse(colMeans(mtcars[3])>=240,mtcars[2],0) +
  ifelse(colMeans(mtcars[3])>=230,mtcars[4],0) +
  ifelse(colMeans(mtcars[3])>=220,mtcars[6],0)
```

I get an error of: non-numeric argument to binary operator

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a single column, we don't need `colMeans`

```
ifelse(rep(mean(mtcars[,3])>=240, nrow(mtcars)),mtcars[,2],0) +
     ifelse(rep(mean(mtcars[,3])>=230, nrow(mtcars)),mtcars[,4],0) +
     ifelse(rep(mean(mtcars[,3])>=220, nrow(mtcars)),mtcars[,6],0)
#[1] 112.620 112.875  95.320 113.215 178.440 108.460 248.570  65.190  98.150 126.440 126.440 184.070 183.730
#[14] 183.780 210.250 220.424 235.345  68.200  53.615  66.835  99.465 153.520 153.435 248.840 178.845  67.935
#[27]  93.140 114.513 267.170 177.770 338.570 111.780
```

---

Based on the condition showed, the input 'test' from `mean` or `colMeans` return a single value i.e. TRUE/FALSE, but the 'yes', 'no' are of different length i.e. `mtcars[2]`.  If we need the whole column, either we replicate the arguments or use `if/else`

```
f1 <- function(dat, colind1, colind2, val) {
               if(mean(dat[[colind1]]) >= val) dat[[colind2]] else 0
  }
f1(mtcars, 3, 2, 240) + f1(mtcars, 3, 4, 230) + f1(mtcars, 3, 6, 220)
#[1] 112.620 112.875  95.320 113.215 178.440 108.460 248.570  65.190  98.150 126.440 126.440 184.070 183.730
#[14] 183.780 210.250 220.424 235.345  68.200  53.615  66.835  99.465 153.520 153.435 248.840 178.845  67.935
#[27]  93.140 114.513 267.170 177.770 338.570 111.780
```